# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this code,

```
 idTirada: string;
  tirada: Tirada;

  constructor(private tiradaService: TiradaService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute ) { 

    this.idTirada = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.tiradaService.getTirada( this.idTirada ) 
        .subscribe( resp => {
          this.tirada = resp;      
          console.log (resp)
        });              

  }
```

I read Firebase with tiraradaService and it returns an array with the information

```
{arc: "-M9TuPty-oGAmgmnh0WL", camp: "massia", data: "2020-06-14T09:47:32.878Z", plens: "0", punts: "135", …}
```

I show it in the HTML

```
<ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle>{{ tirada.arc }}</ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card-header>
```

But it gives me this error, that if I refresh the information several times it disappears, it is as if I loaded the HTML before the data and did not know where to get the information

```
core.js:6228 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'arc' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

When Angular renders the view before `tirada` got a value assigned, it causes an exception. `?.` stops evaluating when `tirada` is null or undefined, which usually happens when data is fetched async, for example from the server which can take quite some time.

The next time change detection recognises a change, the bindings will be re-evaluated. When `tirada` then has a value it will bind `tirada.arc`.

So use `?.` in your template HTML.

```
<ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-subtitle>{{ tirada?.arc }}</ion-card-subtitle>
</ion-card-header>
```

Comment: Or if you are using a custom class, you can create a new instance of that class in the constructor: `this.tirada = new Tirada();`